# Semiconductor Li-ion batteries

Tags: materials, semiconductors

I have recently come across the concept of semiconductor Li-ion batters, for instance carbonised polyacenic semiconductor (PAS) Li-doped materials.

I am not sure how common it is for a battery to be formed of a semiconductor, and are their any other examples?

Do all Li-ion polymer batteries involve a semiconducting component?

How do these differ from metallic batteries?

Is there an advantage?